# Use awk to limit a flag based on two columns of a file

Tags: awk

I have an awk command that compares column 3 based on column 2.  If column 2 (ID) is equal, it compares column 3 (coupon) to see if the values are different and flags them as 0 or 1.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" ";} NR==1 { print; next } { print $0, ($2 == a) ? (($3 == b) ? "0" : "1") : "0"; a = $2; b = $3 }' testv1.txt
```

Sample input.

```
Month    ID Coupon  Reprice
2013-12  2  4.00    
2014-01  2  4.00    
2014-02  2  4.50    
2014-03  2  4.50    
2013-10  3  3.00    
2013-11  3  3.00    
2013-12  3  3.25    
2014-01  3  3.25    
2014-02  3  3.25    
2014-03  3  3.50
```

This is the current output.

```
Month    ID Coupon  Reprice
2013-12  2  4.00    0
2014-01  2  4.00    0
2014-02  2  4.50    1
2014-03  2  4.50    0
2013-10  3  3.00    0
2013-11  3  3.00    0
2013-12  3  3.25    1
2014-01  3  3.25    0
2014-02  3  3.25    0
2014-03  3  3.50    1
```

What I would like is, if the ID is the same, only let the reprice flag value 1 occur one time, like so (the last reprice flag would be 0 instead of 1).

```
Month    ID Coupon  Reprice
2013-12  2  4.00    0
2014-01  2  4.00    0
2014-02  2  4.50    1
2014-03  2  4.50    0
2013-10  3  3.00    0
2013-11  3  3.00    0
2013-12  3  3.25    1
2014-01  3  3.25    0
2014-02  3  3.25    0
2014-03  3  3.50    0
```

Sorry about the posting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an associative array (also, next time provide a sample input):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" ";} NR==1 { print; next } { v = ($2 == a) ? (($3 == b) ? "0" : "1") : "0"; } v == "1" && reprice[$2] { v = "0"; } { print $0, v; a = $2; b = $3 } v == "1" {reprice[$2] = 1}' testv1.txt
```

Explanation:

`{ v = ($2 == a) ? (($3 == b) ? "0" : "1") : "0"; }` calculates the value for the Reprice column

`v == "1" {reprice[$2] = 1}` marks that we have seen a reprice (which only triggers if a reprice happened, namely when `v == "1"`)

`v == "1" && reprice[$2] { v = "0"; }` will set reprice to `"0"` when you've already seen a reprice for the given id.

`{ print $0, v; a = $2; b = $3 }` prints the data

Comment: @mmm i made an edit.  If you want to see more about associative arrays in awk, try to figure out what `awk '!x[$0]++'` does